# Perl File Update After Each Print Statement

Tags: perl, filehandle

When I write a file in Perl, the complete content of each Print statement is getting updated on the file once the program is complete.

Is there a way in which the file can be updated after each print statement is executed ?

I tried setting $|=1, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Can you show the code that suffers and explain more clearly what is not updated? (How do you even know how often a file is updated?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `$|` to non-zero enables autoflush on *only the currently selected* output file handle. By default this is `STDOUT` unless you have called `select` to change it

That means that, if you have opened a new handle to a file, `$|` will not affect its behaviour

Instead, you can use the `IO::Handle` module's `autoflush` method. There is no need to `use IO::Handle` as `IO::File`, which subclasses `IO::Handle`, is loaded on demand by any version of perl since v5.14

It would look like this

```
open my $fh, '>', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;
$fh->autoflush;
```

After this, anything sent to the file using `print $fh` is immediately flushed to disk